# Stuck with return statement within catch block

Tags: java, android, return, try-catch

I'm developing an android application where I use the following snippet:

```
  private Boolean updateAffectedProducts(boolean isOnline) {
        try {
            if (isOnline) {
                METHOD_NAME = "_updateAffectedDesignchangeInfo";

                String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;

                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                request.addProperty("InventoryId",
                        updateAffectedProduct_Model.getInventory_Id());
                request.addProperty("AttributeId",
                        updateAffectedProduct_Model.getAttributeId());
                request.addProperty("AttributeValue",
                        updateAffectedProduct_Model.getAttributeName());
                request.addProperty("OldValue",
                        updateAffectedProduct_Model.getCurrentValue());
                request.addProperty("NewValue",
                        updateAffectedProduct_Model.getNewValue());
                request.addProperty("Comments",
                        updateAffectedProduct_Model.getComments());
                request.addProperty("ClientId",
                        updateAffectedProduct_Model.getClientId());
                request.addProperty("ProjectId",
                        updateAffectedProduct_Model.getProjectId());
                request.addProperty("ProductId",
                        updateAffectedProduct_Model.getProductId());
                request.addProperty("WorkflowTransId",
                        updateAffectedProduct_Model.getWorkflowTransId());
                request.addProperty("BulletinId",
                        updateAffectedProduct_Model.getBulletinId());
                request.addProperty("CreatedBy",
                        updateAffectedProduct_Model.getCreatedBy());

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;

                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                if (envelope.getResponse().toString().equals("true")) {
                    return getDesignChangeInfo(isOnline);
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } 

            else {

                String insertQuery="Insert into ProductAttributeChangeLog (ProductAttributeChangeId,AttributeId,ProjectID,ProductID, ClientID, OldValue, NewValue,InventoryID, LogComments, WorkFlowTransId, BulletinID, CreatedBy, Createdtime, IsDeleted) values " +
                        "('"+"1"+"','"+updateAffectedProduct_Model.getAttributeId()+"', '"+updateAffectedProduct_Model.getProjectId()+"', '"
                        +updateAffectedProduct_Model.getProductId()+"','"
                        +updateAffectedProduct_Model.getClientId()+"', '"
                        +updateAffectedProduct_Model.getCurrentValue()+"','"
                        +updateAffectedProduct_Model.getNewValue()+"', '"
                        +updateAffectedProduct_Model.getInventory_Id()+"', '"+""+"','"
                        +updateAffectedProduct_Model.getComments()+"','"
                        +updateAffectedProduct_Model.getWorkflowTransId()+"','"
                        +updateAffectedProduct_Model.getBulletinId()+"','"
                        +updateAffectedProduct_Model.getCreatedBy()+"','"
                        +sdf.format(now)+"','"+""+"')";

                //database.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(insertQuery);

                try
                {
                ContentValues insertProductAttributeChangeLog=new ContentValues();
                insertProductAttributeChangeLog.put("ProductAttributeChangeId", 1);
                insertProductAttributeChangeLog.put("AttributeId", updateAffectedProduct_Model.getAttributeId());
                insertProductAttributeChangeLog.put("ProjectID", updateAffectedProduct_Model.getProjectId());
                insertProductAttributeChangeLog.put("ProductID", updateAffectedProduct_Model.getProductId());
                insertProductAttributeChangeLog.put("ClientID", updateAffectedProduct_Model.getClientId());
                insertProductAttributeChangeLog.put("OldValue", updateAffectedProduct_Model.getCurrentValue());
                insertProductAttributeChangeLog.put("NewValue", updateAffectedProduct_Model.getNewValue());
                insertProductAttributeChangeLog.put("InventoryID", updateAffectedProduct_Model.getInventory_Id());
                insertProductAttributeChangeLog.put("LogComments", updateAffectedProduct_Model.getComments());
                insertProductAttributeChangeLog.put("Comment", updateAffectedProduct_Model.getComments());
                insertProductAttributeChangeLog.put("WorkFlowTransId", updateAffectedProduct_Model.getWorkflowTransId());
                insertProductAttributeChangeLog.put("BulletinId", updateAffectedProduct_Model.getBulletinId());
                insertProductAttributeChangeLog.put("CreatedBy", updateAffectedProduct_Model.getCreatedBy());
                insertProductAttributeChangeLog.put("UpdatedBy", updateAffectedProduct_Model.getCreatedBy());
                insertProductAttributeChangeLog.put("Createdtime", sdf.format(now));
                insertProductAttributeChangeLog.put("UpdatedTime", sdf.format(now));
                insertProductAttributeChangeLog.put("IsDeleted", "false");


                database.getWritableDatabase().insert("ProductAttributeChangeLog", null, insertProductAttributeChangeLog);

                database.getWritableDatabase().close();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                e.printStackTrace();    
                }

                //Cursor c=database.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ProductAttributeChangeLog where ", selectionArgs)

    /*          //database.getWritableDatabase().execSQL("INSERT INTO Queries (Queries,QueryType) values('"+insertQuery+"',"+"'0')");
                ContentValues insertQueryContent=new ContentValues();
                insertQueryContent.put("Queries", insertQuery);
                insertQueryContent.put("QueryType", "0");
                database.getWritableDatabase().insert("Queries", null, insertQueryContent);*/

                 getDesignChangeInfo(isOnline);
                return true;

            }
        } 
        catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            this.e = e;
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            this.e = e;
            return false;
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            this.e = e;
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            this.e = e;

        return false;
        }


    }
```

while I'm debugging the code. The return statement in the last catch block `return false;` is executed without executing `this.e = e;` and `this.e` is `null`. If I remove the last catch block

```
 catch (Exception e) { 
        this.e = e;
        return false;
    }
```

then the return statement in the following catch block is executed

```
  catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        this.e = e;
        return false;
    }
```

What mistakes did I make?

Comment: It is a duplicate. It is the same question from the same person... Why do you ask it twice?

Comment: also, its hard to believe that `this.e is null` is actually true

Answer (score 0):

If the method doesn't know what to do with the exception, why catch it at all? I'd just throw it and let the calling method take care of things. Then perhaps you might even get away with a void return type.

Also, as an unrelated side note: methods should only do one thing. They should be small. Yours is truly massive and should most assuredly be broken up into smaller pieces.

EDIT: About why your exceptions aren't being caught. You have constructed a nested try block that silently disposes of any exceptions. Your outer try block never has a clue. This is another example of why it's a bad thing to catch generic exceptions.